When calling the mysql_query() function, I see the error message "mysql client ran out of memory", so I ask a question
I am getting a lot of help here.
I am grateful for this.
I would like to ask a question because I had the following experience while interoperating with MySQL 5.7 server in MFC.
A query was sent to the MySQL server with mysql_query("select ..." ) and the results were received.
The query was clearly grammatically correct and was working normally.
The resultset was acquired using "mysql_store_result()", the data was accessed in one row units using "mysql_fetch_row()", and the resultset was released using "mysql_free_result()".
As far as I know, loading into client-level memory is done with the mysql_store_result() function.
So, I think it is most natural and understandable that the "mysql client ran out of memory" error occurs during the call to the "mysql_store_result()" function.
That is, what I know is
When calling the "mysql_query()" function, I knew that the query results were not being loaded into the client-side memory.
However, sometimes, after calling the ""mysql_query()" function, an error occurs, and in the message content extracted by the "mysql_error()" function, you see the message "mysql client ran out of memory" and make a query.
So my judgment is
"I was curious about whether the following functions exist within the mysql_query() function, as well as whether the result of the query performed by the Mysql server was successful.

When the server performs a query, the results will be loaded into memory on the server. At this time, the server notifies the corresponding memory size inside the mysql_query() function on the client side, compares the size with the available memory size on the client side in advance, and determines in advance whether the client side can accept the result. , error codes and error messages were generated. And the function returns an error, and does the mysql_error() function output the message "mysql client ran out of memory"?

I am curious about this and would like to ask a question.

Or, the mysql_query() function simply loads low-level memory in addition to whether the query execution is successful, the mysql_store_result() function converts data into a structure called resulset, and "mysql_fetch_row" etc. retrieves data in one row units. I think I'm approaching it too.

Unless in cases 1 and 2, it was determined that the error message "mysql client ran out of memory" could not be output as a result of the failure of the "mysql_query()" function...
I have a question.
This may be an advanced question, but I hope you can consider it as a simple curiosity as an engineer and help.
I hope everyone who reads this long article will be blessed.
I found that the current client-side software measured the size of memory in use and the size of available memory at regular intervals, and as a result of printing the size less than 10 seconds before the error message was output, the memory in use ranged from about 10 MB. It indicates that it is 150MB and that up to 2GB can be allocated as it is a 32-bit application, and the log file confirms that the available size is also more than 1GB.
So, I wanted to know the cause of the error, and because the program died due to the error, the memory measurements at the time could not be output. I did not know whether the error occurred because the mysql_query() function allocated a very large amount of memory for the result.
However, what I know is that the mysql_store_result() function would allocate memory, but the symptom was that the mysql_query() function returned an error, and the error message "mysql client ran out of memory" was output by the mysql_error() function. It's true.
The expression in the above article is somewhat ambiguous, indicating that the amount of available memory measured at certain times remains very large.
The memory in use was 150 MB, and the available memory measurement was over 1 GB.
Of course, this is a record from 10 seconds ago, but it is difficult to judge that the 2GB limit known as the maximum size for 32-bit applications was exceeded in less than 10 seconds.

Are you really still using the obsolete mysql extension? It was deprecated many years ago, and removed entirely in PHP 7.0. You should be using mysqli or PDO.

What were you doing?  How much RAM do you have?  Were other apps running on the same machine?  What changes did you make ty my.cnf?

What app language are you using?  PHP removed "mysql_query" onlg ago.
